# Can't Connect Spring Application with MySql running on Docker. but working on intellij and MySql WorkBench

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I'm trying to run the spring boot application on docker with a connection with MySQL when I run the application on IntelliJ with MySQL running on docker it works correctly when I open MySql WorkBench the docker MySQL is working fine but when I try to run the application on docker it didn't work.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test
    username: root
    password: root
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect:  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        format_sql: true
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:19-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE  8080
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
ADD ./target/springmysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**connector**

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

**error**

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:444) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:237) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:36) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]        
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]       
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.<init>(Database.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1348) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]      
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1419) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]  
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]  
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]    
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at com.example.springmysql.SpringmysqlApplication.main(SpringmysqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:483) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:944) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:814) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:539) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:594) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        ... 56 common frames omitted

2023-02-24T21:13:03.263Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure
/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1752) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5] 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1132) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]  
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]    
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.3.jar!/:3.0.3]
        at com.example.springmysql.SpringmysqlApplication.main(SpringmysqlApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]  
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]   
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1748) ~[spring-beans-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResultSet(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.getTables(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:564) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]   
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final] 
        at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar!/:6.1.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.5.jar!/:6.0.5]  
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:824) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
        ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i guess the application in dockerfile has no connection to your other dockerfile with the mysql. you should add a connection to it and put it in one "virtual" network.

Comment: @muescha I tried to run both on the same network in docker but not working.
what do you mean but "virtual" network?

Comment: it is called bridge network. you create a network with `docker network create my-net` and then you can run a container in the same network: `docker create --name my-nginx --network my-net --publish 8080:80 nginx:latest`

Comment: in the network then you not point to `jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test` but to the name of the container instead as the hostname. for example `jdbc:mysql://mysqldb/bootdb` when you run the mysql container with the name `mysqldb` with this command `docker container run --name mysqldb ...`

Comment: Source: https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-mysql